# What is a good strategy for updating lot of rows in postgersql?

Tags: postgresql, update

I have an `inventory` table which contains `item_id` and the `quantity` remaining of the item (And also some other meta data). I have an administrator update the inventory by uploading a CSV file which contains the `item_id` and the quantity remaining.

1. Run `update for each row in the CSV file. If my CSV file contains 1 million rows, I will end up sending 1 million update statements from my application server to the database server.
2. Construct 1 million update queries and send them in a batch (JDBC allows batched statements)

At first glance approach number 2 looks like a better solution. But then can 1 million statements be batched? What happens if one of the statement fails for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to import the CSV file into a staging table. Either an `unlogged` table which you only create once, or a temp table which you  create immediately before the import.

Something along the lines:

```
create temp table inventory_import (item_id integer primary key, quantity integer);
copy inventory_import from '/path/to/file.csv' ... ;

update inventory i
  set quantity = im.quantity
from inventory_import im
where i.item_id = im.item_id;
```

Comment: If you use a low `fillfactor` and don't update any indexed columns, performance will be even better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But how do you drive this flow from application layer? I mean you will have a good amount of users uploading CSV files to make changes to inventory that they care about.

Comment: I think this approach makes sense as a one time update that you would do when you are within the database machine, right?

Comment: @Ashwin: with multiple users, you can use one temp table for each user.

Comment: Postgres has no problem updating 1Μ rows in a single transaction?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: no, why do you think it would?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  With Oracle this used to be a problem.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: I never had problems in Oracle updating millions if not hundred of millions of rows (other than performance). In fact: committing more frequently (=update less rows) makes things slower in Oracle, not faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This would mean that my application server has to upload the CSV file to the database server and then do the operations that you said, right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What if the application server does not have access to the file system of the database server (it will not be able to upload the CSV file to the database server in the first place)?

Comment: @Ashwin: then use `\copy` or something equivalent which reads the data from the client's file system and does a bulk insert into the temp table